# Why is the behaviour of this code undefined in C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I've been given this code and I'm not quite sure why its behaviour is undefined. My guess is that it has something to do with the memory locations of the two strings and the location(s)' comparison in the if condition.

```
int main(void) { 
  char *str1 = "xyz"; 
  char *str2 = "xyz";

  if (str1 == str2) {
     printf("Same!\n");
  }  else {
     printf("Not Same!\n");
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It is not undefined. Section 6.4.5 defines this behavior. (If it was undefined, the output could be "I like pie!". It's just unspecified.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's unspecified (not undefined, there's a subtle distinction) as to whether identical string constants are folded to occupy the same memory.

`C++11, 6.4.5 String literals /6` states:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Both `str1` and `str2` are pointers to a block of memory containing the four characters `{ 'x', 'y', 'z', '\0'}` and they are, by definition, non-modifiable.

That means the compiler is free to set both those variables to point to the *same* block of memory, for efficiency, if it so desires.

Hence `str1` and `str2` (I'm talking about the pointers, obviously the *content* behind the pointers is identical) may be identical or not.

Comment: I'd further this to say many compilers have merging common literals as a forcible setting  that can be forced on, forced off, or left to the discretion of the compiler/linker.

Comment: It's the same as asking whether the compiler gets the two 3's from different places or whether it gets both 3's from the same place  in code like `int i = 3; int j = 3;`. Except because you have a pointer to the initialized value, you can tell which way it does it. The compiler is free to do it either way.

Comment: I'd be careful there, @David, that's a different situation: (1) `i` and `j` aren't pointers, and (2) the things they represent are modifiable so must be kept distinct.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That's why I was careful to say "whether it gets both 3's from the same place", not whether it puts them in the same place. And no, they're not modifiable. Those 3's are constants in the *source code*. A program cannot modify its own source code.

Comment: @WhozCraig, that's a valid point but nothing to do with the standard whatsoever, which is what my answer is focusing on.

Comment: @paxdiablo It has nothing to do with the standard, but *everything* to do with the specificity (or lack thereof) stated *in* the standard, which was what my comment was focusing on. (and +1, nice answer)

Answer (score 1):

"xyz" is a string literal which is put in to "Read-only" section gets mapped into the process space as read-only (which is why you can't change it).

so both `str1` and `str2` are pointing to same address. This is the reason for `printf("Same!\n");` got executed.

This is platform dependent. Refer [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Answer (score 0):

C does not support string comparison operator so while comparing strings using  == operator it actually compares string addresses and because it is not defined that  "xyz" string constant will have same memory address in Read only memory. it is dependent on compiler and machine.

Comment: What?So you mean two similar strings stored in different locations will be unequal?

Comment: @SheerFish: Two different locations will be unequal. He's comparing addresses.

Comment: @SheerFish Its up to compiler whether it stores identical string in same memory or different and == operator compares compares base address of string as both ptr will point to starting address of read only string.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He said `while comparing strings it actually compares string addresses` about C.So `strcmp()` came to my mind where the content of the strings are compared, and the answer is positive if they are same.But yes, in this case the OP is comparing pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is undefined because it depends on how compiler optimizes the strings. The result cannot be generally defined without knowing what compiler with what options is used.